# Play Akka cluster dist

Tags: playframework, sbt-native-packager, akka-cluster

I am building an app with Play as frontend and akka cluster as backend. Right now both are under the same sbt project. With "dist" in sbt, I could only get one .zip package which has the script to start the play as well as akka cluster. So I am wondering is there are a way to generate multiple packages such as one for Play, one for akka cluster, so that I can easily deploy each. Or is there any recommended good practices for this kind of project?

Comment: You could use sbt subprojects and generate distinct *.zip per each subproject

Answer (score 0):

You can define two `sbt` targets with differrent main classes but it isn't a good pratice. The proper way is creating two subprojects and package each of them separatly.